# How to get unicode decimal/hex value from a chinese word in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In Dart/Flutter, given a Mandarin word "中", how to get the Unicode hex (4E2D) or decimal (20013) value?

I get the value from this [website](https://pages.ucsd.edu/%7Edkjordan/resources/unicodemaker.html).

I can only convert the word into hex by doing `HEX.encode(utf8.encode("中"));`, which is not the Unicode value I need. I am very confused, need some explanation here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utf8.encode will give you the utf-8 byte values, but you are actually wanting the utf-16 code points.

This example shows the values for the utf8 bytes and utf16 code points.

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  
  const input = '中';
  print('Input: $input');
  
  print('-----------------');
  print('Check UTF8 Values');
  final bytes = utf8.encode(input);
  print('Bytes: $bytes');
  for (final byte in bytes) {
    print('Byte Value [$byte] Converted to hex 0x${byte.toRadixString(16)}');
  }
  
  print('---------------------');
  print('Check CodeUnit Values');
  final codeUnits = input.codeUnits;
  print('Code Units: $codeUnits');
  for (final codeUnit in codeUnits) {
    print('CodeUnit Value [$codeUnit] Converted to hex 0x${codeUnit.toRadixString(16)}');
  }
  
}
```

And the output:

```
Input: 中
-----------------
Check UTF8 Values
Bytes: [228, 184, 173]
Byte Value [228] Converted to hex 0xe4
Byte Value [184] Converted to hex 0xb8
Byte Value [173] Converted to hex 0xad
---------------------
Check CodeUnit Values
Code Units: [20013]
CodeUnit Value [20013] Converted to hex 0x4e2d
```

While this works for your specific character, if you are working with input that contains surrogate pairs you may want to look at [string.runes](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/runes.html) instead of string.codeUnits

Answer (score 1):

To get the decimal or unicode value from a Chinese word, try any of the following.

```
String mandarinWord = '中';
int codePoint = mandarinWord.runes.first;
String unicodeHex = codePoint.toRadixString(16).toUpperCase(); // returns the unicode hex "4E2D"
String unicodeDecimal = codePoint.toString(); // this returns "20013"
```

Alternatively, you could also do:

```
String mandarinWord = '中';
String unicodeHex = mandarinWord.codeUnitAt(0).toRadixString(16).toUpperCase(); // returns the unicode hex "4E2D"
int unicodeDecimal = mandarinWord.codeUnitAt(0); // this returns 20013
```